# How can I ssh inside local server I created through vagrant by bypassing Key based authentication?

Tags: linux, ssh, server, vagrant, public-key-encryption

I am doing the configuring Linux web server course from Udacity. In the course instructor first shows how to create a server and log in using a password. Then goes ahead and shows how to set up key-based authentication.

Steps I followed:

1. Make sure logged in as student (user in server)
2. mkdir .ssh (in home directory, this is the special directory where all key related files must be stored)
3. Then create a new file in this directory called authorized_keys
   touch .ssh/authorized_keys
   This is another special file that will store all of the public keys that this account is allowed to use for authentication, with one key per line in that file.
4. Back on local machine read contents of linuxCourse.pub (cat /home/tdk/.ssh/linuxCourse.pub). Copy them and paste it on .ssh/authorized_keys file in server. Save it. contents are

   ssh-rsa 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 usr@usr-machine-name
5. The final thing that we need to do is setup some specific file permissions on the authorized_key file and the SSH directory. This is a security measure that ssh enforces to ensure other users cannot gain access to your account. We do so by
   `chmod 700 .ssh` (on ssh directory)
   and
   `chmod 644 .ssh/authorized_keys` (on file)
6. NOw to login

   ssh student@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -i ~/.ssh/linuxCourse

After setting it up I could still login through the password so I edited the sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and changed Password Authentication from yes to no. After that restarted the ssh service

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

After that, I tried to ssh into the server but got error

```
$ ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -i ~/.ssh/linuxCourse
vagrant@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I tried vagrant ssh-config git following output

```
$ vagrant ssh-config
The provider for this Vagrant-managed machine is reporting that it
is not yet ready for SSH. Depending on your provider this can carry
different meanings. Make sure your machine is created and running and
try again. Additionally, check the output of `vagrant status` to verify
that the machine is in the state that you expect. If you continue to
get this error message, please view the documentation for the provider
you're using.
```

vagrant status gives following

```
$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

default                   poweroff (virtualbox)

The VM is powered off. To restart the VM, simply run `vagrant up`
```

vagrant up gives the following error

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' version '20190514.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "5345b2d8-c7af-472c-a343-b02076f47910", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Incompatible configuration requested. (VERR_INCOMPATIBLE_CONFIG)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Tried to debug got following response:

```
$ sudo ssh student@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -i ~/.ssh/linuxCourse -vvv
[sudo] password for tdk: 
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 127.0.0.1 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tdk/.ssh/linuxCourse type 0
debug1: identity file /home/tdk/.ssh/linuxCourse-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:2222 as 'student'
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:2222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [127.0.0.1]:2222
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:KakFoo+OYhTntz0n1KPTlKcCsCblomPAHw/7ue1dX0U
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:2222
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:2222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [127.0.0.1]:2222
debug1: Host '[127.0.0.1]:2222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tdk/.ssh/linuxCourse RSA SHA256:fae0R+3lMwmQFidjwzP//1Zc0CNaaMwJxy+EG+wBOtE explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/tdk/.ssh/linuxCourse RSA SHA256:fae0R+3lMwmQFidjwzP//1Zc0CNaaMwJxy+EG+wBOtE explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
student@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Checking auth log gives following results:

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
Sep 14 13:39:11 replacedwithfake sudo:      fakeusername : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/fakeusername/codes/courses/configuring_linux_webservers ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ssh student@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -i /home/fakeusername/.ssh/linuxCourse
Sep 14 13:39:11 replacedwithfake sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 14 13:39:11 replacedwithfake sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I have tried to ssh using both root and as the user that created the server. Nothing works. I have checked all the methods to solve this issue and all of them involve logging into the server and then fixing it. Bt I can't log in.

I believe the only solution is to ssh to the local server without a key. How can I do that? Or is there anything else I can do?

Comment: In your entire question I see no mention of you adding `~/.ssh/linuxCourse.pub` to `~vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys` inside the vagrant box ... how do you expect passwordless authentication to work without that?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. I have done it. Please check the details on the steps I followed added to the description while setting up the key-based authentication.

Comment: How did you go about `step 4`?  What are the permissions on `~student/.ssh` and `~student/.ssh/authorized_keys`? What does the content of `~student/.ssh/authorized_keys` look like?

Comment: Contents were: ssh-rsa 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 usr@usr-machine-name

Comment: I am not sure about what the permissions on `~student/.ssh ` and `~student/.ssh/authorized_keys` were when I created them. And now can't check as I am unable to ssh into the server.